# Error publishing on Liferay, No class StagedModelDataHandlerRegistryUtil

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I have an error publishing on Liferay.
[image]

I have 2 patch installed, these 2: de-50-7010, hotfix-6581-7010

Comment: You should give more information about your error, for example, paste the error from the log file.
You can also try activating DEBUG traces.
If you are an enterprise customer, you can open a ticket to Liferay Support here: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make sure it includes your own code to be on-topic for stackoverflow [help/on-topic] or carry it over to the Liferay Forums (with detailed description), where this question would be on topic. As you seem to have a supported version, you might also want to file a support ticket.